# JasperReports wrong font in exported pdf

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I have a problem with Jasper Report (version 6.0). I'm using Jasper Report to create a pdf report of some params that I pass using Java. I created the .JRXML file using jasper studio and I set text field to use "Times New Roman" font.

```
<staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="570" height="100" uuid="56a5a7af-9b84-479a-8182-0ab30d974d79"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[TSOME TEXT]]></text>
</staticText>
```

In the preview provided from jasper studio the font is correctly set but when I execute the java code the output pdf has a different font, not the expected "Times New Roman". I tried also to set this property in .JRXML:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name" value="Times New Roman"/>
```

But it doesn't works. Someone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You should use font extensions

Comment: Also for a common font like "Times New Roman"?

Comment: it all depends on font availability with JVM, if your server JVM has access to the "Times New Roman" font, then it'll work. or else you must use font extension.

Comment: There are no common fonts :)